# User Defined Function in PyQGIS Script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a Python script that is working fine from Processing->Toolbox->User Scripts. However, I have put some user defined functions in "my_functions.py" that I can call from "Timing_Advance.py".

The problem is, when I edit the functions in "my_functions.py" in the QGIS script editor, I have to restart QGIS for the changes to take effect. This is perhaps because, when I restart QGIS, it makes a "my_fucntions.pyc" file and keeps it in the same location. The .pyc file is not update when I edit the user defined functions in "my_functions.py".

How can I update the my_functions.pyc file after editing, without having to restart QGIS?

UPDATE 24th Jan 2017
Looks like including the following lines isn't making any difference either

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\EDEYARI\.qgis2\processing\scripts')
import py_compile
py_compile.compile(r'C:\Users\EDEYARI\.qgis2\processing\scripts\my_functions.py')

import my_functions
```

If I add some dummy lines like a "print" and re-run the script, the print doesn't give the desired output, till I re-start QGIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile('path/to/my_functions.py')
```

Comment: i added the suggested lines and then I added a dummy piece of code print "hi" in my_functions.py. if the code worked then I would have seen the response in the python console, but nope

Comment: @Arindam - Hmm, perhaps this post might help: [Re-import custom functions without restarting QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201404/re-import-custom-functions-without-restarting-qgis)

Comment: I must be missing something elementary. I added these lines      import     imp, my_functions  
imp.reload(my_functions)  
from my_functions import *                                                                   but now I get the error "See log for Details"

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just removed "imp" and it worked like a charm. Found the answer here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517038/python-refresh-reload>

Comment: @Arindam - Ahh well done for solving your problem! You should post it as an **answer** and accept it by clicking the green-faded tick :)

Comment: I've added the info about user80602's link and the imp library name change in the post referenced by Arindam, so I think this one could be deleted?