# Reloading own lib in QGIS python console?

Tags: pyqgis

I´m working on a main script with additional code based in a lib folder like this:

`main.py`
`\mylib`
  `util.py` (contains the class Utility) 
  `node.py`
in `main.py` I´ve imported mylib like this:

```
from mylib.util import Utility
x = Utility()
```

It seems like QGIS python console caches the `mylib` on startup - changes made to the Utility class made after startup is ignored.

Is there a way to reload mylib without restarting QGIS?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Re-import custom functions without restarting QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201404/re-import-custom-functions-without-restarting-qgis)

Comment: I´ve tried the reload approach, but I get a console error like: reload() argument must be module. Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to reload lib folders as I normally just reload the _main.py_ file :)

Comment: Hi again Joseph. I´ve figured out, that reload(mylib) doesn´t throw an error - but on the other hand util.py isn´t reloaded. Thanks for your advice anyway. I´ll try searching some more

Comment: Please note that there is a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.